# suds not returning webservice methods

Tags: python, web-services, wsdl, suds

I am using the following python code to display all methods offered by a webservice generated from a wsdl version 2.0 file.
The url is the following: 
    http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/UserService?wsdl2

Using the above url, the browser displays the wsdl file but when using this url in a python application below, it returns only the following info and nothing related to the webservice methods in question.

### Python code

```
from suds.wsse import *
from suds.client import Client

myclient = Client("http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/UserService?wsdl2")
print myclient
```

### output

```
Suds ( https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ )  version: 0.3.9 GA  build: R659-20100219
```

it should be returing the methods available in the webservice as in the example        https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation

any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the `/tmp/suds` directory. Also try passing `cache=None` in the Client constructor:

```
myclient = Client("http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/UserService?wsdl2", cache=None)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that still suds doesn't support WSDL 2.

See https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ticket/479